# How do I create a stack-based character array that can be captured (const copied) by a block closure?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to create a stack-based C string (i.e. char[]) that can be captured (by const copy) by a block closure.  The basic idea is like this:

```
char myString[16] = {0};
// ... put something into myString.
dispatch_block_t block = ^(){
    const size_t len = strlen(myString);
    if (len)
        NSLog(@"Not zero length");
};
```

But doing that causes this compiler complaint:

```
error: cannot refer to declaration with an array type inside block
```

It occurs to me that I could put the char array into a struct, but that seems kinda ugly. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with stack allocation is that the stack frame disapears once you leave the  function but the block code still remains and may refer to variables in that stack frame.   Blocks handle this by allocating and copying all values refered by it to the heap including variables declared with __block. In theory they should be able to copy statically sized arrays but for some reason it's not supported. Mind you there could very well be technical issues that I'm not aware of related to arrays.

So I the simplest solution I see is to use malloc/free:

```
char *myString = calloc(16,1);

dispatch_block_t block = ^(){
    const size_t len = strlen(myString);
    if (len)
        NSLog(@"Not zero length");
    free(myString);
};
```

So long as you don't need to re-use the block multiple times you are OK. If you need to re-use the block then wrap myString in a NSData object that you can refer to in your block and get rid of the free.

```
char *myString = calloc(16,1);
NSData *myStringData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:myString length:16 freeWhenDone:YES];

dispatch_block_t block = ^(){
    const char *myString = myStringData.bytes;
    const size_t len = strlen(myString);
    if (len)
        NSLog(@"Not zero length");
};
```

Comment: Yeah... I understand how the stack and heap relate to block closures. I'm specifically looking for a way to get the const-copy capture behavior with a fixed-size array type with clean syntax. It looks like there just isn't a clean way, and I'll have to use a struct to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Having been a week at this point, I'm starting to feel confident that there's not some magic syntax that I'm simply missing.  For the benefit of future visitors, this is the best way I've found so far to achieve what I'm asking about here:

```
    typedef struct { char string[32]; } StackString;

    StackString foo = {0};
    strcpy(foo.string, "foo");

    dispatch_block_t block = ^(){
        StackString blockFoo = foo;
        NSLog(@"Block String: %s", blockFoo.string);
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        sprintf(foo.string, "i = %d", i);
        NSLog(@"Loop string: %s", foo.string);
        block();
    }
```

The output of which is:

```
2013-03-31 11:30:52.778 TestClosure[98968:303] Loop string: i = 0
2013-03-31 11:30:52.780 TestClosure[98968:303] Block String: foo
2013-03-31 11:30:52.780 TestClosure[98968:303] Loop string: i = 1
2013-03-31 11:30:52.780 TestClosure[98968:303] Block String: foo
2013-03-31 11:30:52.780 TestClosure[98968:303] Loop string: i = 2
2013-03-31 11:30:52.781 TestClosure[98968:303] Block String: foo
2013-03-31 11:30:52.781 TestClosure[98968:303] Loop string: i = 3
2013-03-31 11:30:52.782 TestClosure[98968:303] Block String: foo
2013-03-31 11:30:52.782 TestClosure[98968:303] Loop string: i = 4
2013-03-31 11:30:52.782 TestClosure[98968:303] Block String: foo
```

This convinces me that wrapped in a struct, the fixed size array is const-copied into the block closure just fine.